# Spring roo TrustManager not found by

Tags: sql-server, spring, reverse-engineering, spring-roo, trustmanager

I want to reverse engineer a sql-server database. I've set up a project, create a entity, controller and set up the web mvc.

After this I start the application with tomcat. Call the web-interface and add a record. Everything works fine.

Back to the roo shell (sts-plugin) I tried the `database introspect --schema dbo` command but i got the this tiny feedback: `javax.net.ssl.TrustManager not found by [85]`

A user in an other post mention that you should start the sqljdbc jar with osgi, like this: `osgi start --url  file:///C:/Users/e.zienecker/Downloads/mssql/sqljdbc4-4.0.jar`

But with this i got the following message: `javax/net/ssl/TrustManager`

For more information, my spring roo log:

```
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev 8387857] log opened at 2016-05-31 10:00:38
project --topLevelPackage de.test --projectName DatabaseSample --java 6 --packaging JAR
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev 8387857] log closed at 2016-05-31 10:00:39
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev 8387857] log opened at 2016-05-31 10:00:40
jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database MSSQL
entity jpa --class ~.Person --testAutomatically
field string --fieldName firstName --notNull
field string --fieldName lastName --notNull
field number --fieldName age --type int
field boolean --fieldName driverLicense
web mvc setup
web mvc all --package ~.web
selenium test --controller ~.web.PersonController
perform tests
perform tests
perform package
// [failed] database introspect --schema dbo
osgi start --url  file:///C:/Users/mad/Downloads/mssql/sqljdbc4-4.0.jar
// [failed] database introspect --schema dbo
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the username, password and hostname of the selected database?

You are able to do it executing again `jpa setup` command and providing the necessary parameters like `--userName`, `--password`, etc...

The following sections of the spring roo 1.3.2.RELEASE documentation talks about it:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/command-index.html#command-index-jpa-setup

http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/base-persistence.html#d4e1506

Also, you could configure them using `database properties set` command.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Comment: When I start the application (tomcat run) it works: There are no errors and the app has created the database successfully. When I stop the app and switch back to the shell and run the command `database introspect --schema dbo` I get this error. So it can't be a problem with the database.properties.

Comment: But.. if you try to create new register using a generated application form.. is it working for you? If you execute a `SELECT` statement.. are you getting your created elements? To be able to know what is happening here you could execute the command `development mode` before start your previous script. This will show you more info about the trace on the Spring Roo shell. Try it! Waiting for your answer  ;)

Comment: Yes, when I insert a record via the client I see the record in the database. Only the `introspect` in the shell is not working. I entered the `development mode` command and after this the `database introspect --schema dbo` but I get the same error: `javax/net/ssl/TrustManager`

Comment: I supose that the same error occurs if you try to execute `database reverse engineer`?

Comment: Could you provide more info about the environment, database, java version, etc. to be able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: sts 3.7.3, database sql server 2012, project java version is 1.6 installed is jdk up to 1.8, roo in version 1.3.2

Comment: @jcgarcia is there any new in this issue? We only reproced it in gvnix. Not in spring roo. Thanks in advance.